# When does $\det\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1&1\\x_1&x_2&x_3\\x_2&x_3&x_1\end{smallmatrix}\right)=0$ imply $x_1=x_2=x_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, symmetric-polynomials

**Original question.** Does the condition $$\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\x_1&x_2&x_3\\x_2&x_3&x_1\end{pmatrix}=0$$ imply $x_1=x_2=x_3$?

a) Is this true if we assume $x_{1,2,3}\in\mathbb R$?
b) Is this true if we assume $x_{1,2,3}\in\mathbb C$?

I believe that this is true for real numbers and false for complex numbers. I posted my arguments in the answer below. (But still I would be interested in any alternative solutions and additional insights.)

We might ask about an arbitrary field - but I would not be surprised it the generalized question might be difficult.

**Bonus question.** For which fields the above condition holds? If this is difficult to answer, are there are at least some sufficient or necessary conditions?

Some stuff which immediately comes into mind - and perhaps some of these might be reasonable ways to look at this problem.

- Let us denote $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2,x_3,x_1)$.
- The condition about the determinant basically says that the vectors $\vec u=(1,1,1)$, $\vec x$ and $T(\vec x)$ are linearly dependent.
- Clearly, $T$ is a linear isomorphism and $T^3=id$. If we are working over complex numbers, then the minimal polynomial it $m(t)=t^3-1$ and the eigenvalues are the roots of this polynomial: $1$, $\omega$, $\omega^2$.
- For real numbers, the condition about determinant says that the points $(x_1,x_2)$, $(x_2,x_3)$, $(x_3,x_1)$ are collinear.
- We can forget the linear structure and simply view this as a problem about a polynomial in three variables - we're asking when $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2=0$.

I will add that this question originated from some [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/140317/2022/11/2) - although in that discussion it was just an auxiliary result.

Answer (score 12):

We're looking at the condition
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\x_1&x_2&x_3\\x_2&x_3&x_1\end{pmatrix}=0 \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad x_1=x_2=x_3 \tag{*}$$

a) The condition $(*)$ is true for real numbers.

If this determinant is zero, we have
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_1x_2-x_2x_3-x_3x_1=\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+(x_3-x_1)^2}2=0.$$
We can get zero as a sum of non-negative real numbers only if each of them is zero. So we get
\begin{align*}
(x_1-x_2)^2=(x_2-x_3)^2=(x_3-x_1)^2&=0\\
x_1-x_2=x_2-x_3=x_3-x_1&=0
\end{align*}
which means $x_1=x_2=x_3$.

b) The condition $(*)$ is false for complex numbers.

If suffices to check that for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,\omega,\omega^2)$, where $\omega$ is a third root of unity, we get
$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & \omega & \omega^2 \\
  \omega & \omega^2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
In fact, it is easy to notice that the rows are linearly dependent, since we get the third row if we multiply the second one by $\omega$.

b') All complex matrices which give zero determinant.

The linear transformation $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2,x_3,x_1)$ has three eigenvalues $1$, $\omega$ and $\omega^2$. (The roots of the polynomial $\chi_T(t)=t^3-1$. I.e., we have $\omega^3=1$)

- $\vec v_1=(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda=1$.
- $\vec v_2=(1,\omega,\omega^2)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda=\omega$.
- $\vec v_3=(1,\omega^2,\omega)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda=\omega^2$.

Since $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$, $\vec v_3$ are eigenvectors corresponding to three different eigenvalues, they are linearly independent and they form a basis. Let us have a look at the vector $\vec x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in this basis.

If $\vec x=c_1\vec v_1+c_2\vec v_2+c_3\vec v_3$, then
$$T(\vec x)=c_1\vec v_1+c_2\omega\vec v_2+c_3\omega^2\vec v_3.$$
So the question whether the vectors $\vec v_1,\vec x,T(\vec x)$ are linearly independent is basically a question about the determinant
$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
  c_1 & c_2\omega & c_3\omega^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}=c_2c_3(\omega^2-\omega)
$$
This determinant is zero if and only if $c_2=0$ or $c_3=0$. So to get a zero determinant, we have to take for $\vec x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ a linear combination of $(1,1,1)$ and and eigenvector for one of the two complex eigenvalues. (I.e., $\vec x=c_1\vec v_1+c_2\vec v_2$ or $\vec x=c_1\vec v_1+c_3\vec v_3$.)

Comment: Many compliments.